# products are not showing up in category in magento 1.9

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Products are not showing up in categories and showing error on clicking products. I have done with admin as :

- Product is entered in Magento
- Product is Enabled
- Visibility set to Catalog,Search
- Quantity set to 2
- Inventory is In Stock
- Product set to display on Main Website
- Product is in a catagory

Everything is checked, but no luck. I have tried a cache refresh and re-indexing. Products in home page is showing, on search is working fine, but
on clicking on products through searching I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function addToChildGroup() on null in
>   /home/indiartcare/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php
>   on line 815

Comment: Clutter removed. Some spelling fixed.

Answer (score 0):

check/update category flat index if enabled

Answer (score 0):

**Check 3 more things:**

Catalog->Manage products->Product information->Websites: see if the desired website is checked.

This option appears only if you have a multishop configured, thsu more than 1 website.

Catalog->Manage categories->[your category]->Display settings->Display mode: set it to 'Products only' or 'Statis block and products'

Catalog->Manage categories->[your category]->Display settings->Is anchor: set it to 'Yes

Please try to run reindex in shell folder.

```
php indexer.php --reindexall
```

or in admin panel:

```
System -> Index Management
```